# ChecksumMismatchError: Conda detected a mismatch between the expected content and downloaded content

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, torch

I have installed many many packages including `torch, gpytorch, ...` in the past in Windows, Ubuntu and Mac following this scenario:

```sh
conda create -n env_name
conda activate env_name
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

However, this time on Ubuntu, I interfered the following error on downloading the package which apparently after downloading when checking the checksum, it sees a mismatch. I also tried removing those `*.bz2` files just in case if there is a pre-downloaded file, it didn't work.

```sh
ChecksumMismatchError: Conda detected a mismatch between the expected content and downloaded content
for url 'https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-64/torchaudio-0.9.0-py39.tar.bz2'.
  download saved to: /home/amin/anaconda3/pkgs/torchaudio-0.9.0-py39.tar.bz2
  expected md5: 7224453f68125005e034cb6646f2f0a3
  actual md5: 6bbb8056603453427bbe4cca4b033361

ChecksumMismatchError: Conda detected a mismatch between the expected content and downloaded content
for url 'https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-64/torchvision-0.10.0-py39_cu111.tar.bz2'.
  download saved to: /home/amin/anaconda3/pkgs/torchvision-0.10.0-py39_cu111.tar.bz2
  expected md5: 78b4c927e54b06d7a6d18eec8b3f2d18
  actual md5: 69dd8411c573903db293535017742bd9
```

My system information:

```
Linux SPOT-Server 5.8.0-63-generic #71~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 15 17:46:08 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My `conda --version` is also `4.8.2`.
I also should add that I have same issue on Windows having `conda --version` equal to `4.10.1`.

Comment: Could you please check if the URL works for you directly? And what MD5 sum does the manual result give?

Comment: @merv Yes, both links worked using `wget`. I calculated the checksums manually, in both cases they were equal to `expected md5` in the `Checksum` error.

Comment: Actually, this seems odd - the uploader is not the usual and there are no downloads after 4 days: [torchaudio files](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/torchaudio/files?version=0.9.0) [torchvision files](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/torchvision/files?version=0.10.0) Hopefully, it's just a goof-up by the channel maintainers, but personally, I wouldn't use those builds without knowing more.

Comment: An [issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/63006) has been logged in the pytorch repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PyTorch channel maintainers had an issue when uploading some new package builds, which has since been resolved (see [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/63006)).  The technical cause was uploading new builds with identical versions and build numbers as before, without replacing the previous build. This caused the expected MD5 checksum to correspond to the new upload, but the tarball that was ultimately downloaded still corresponded to the previous upload, leading to a checksum mismatch.